Set redshift's enable_case_sensitive_identifier configuration in VBA code
Our Excel files are connected to our redshift database. redshift doesn't allow uppercase letters in the columns unless I set enable_case_sensitive_identifier to true.
Setting it in the VBA code just breaks the code in the sense that no data is generated, but also no error is generated. In other words, nothing happens when I click the button that runs GenerateData(). As soon as I comment that first line out, it works but the column names are all lower-case.
Is there a way to set enable_case_sensitive_identifier to true in the VBA code? Or is there another way to change the columns to uppercase?
Sub GenerateDate()
    Dim sql As String

    sql = "SET enable_case_sensitive_identifier TO false; select emp_name, buyer_name from MyRedshiftTable"
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
      
    Sheets("Data").Select
    With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("sgwsredshiftdb").ODBCConnection
        .CommandText = sql
    End With
    
        ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
End Sub


Setting enable_case_sensitive_identifier to true also means that case will be used in the SQL for selecting columns.  So is the column name emp_name or something like Emp_Name?  To get Redshift to respect the caps in the column names in the SQL you will need to enclose them in double quotes.  Something like SELECT "Emp_Name" FROM ".

Thanks. Were you able to look at the attached VBA code? I'm doing that in the SQL within the VBA code.

The sql generated in the VBA is select emp_name as "Employee Name", buyer_name as "BUYER Name" ...

What is the DDL (definition) of the table MyRedshiftTable?  Your question is about why enabling enable_case_sensitive_identifier is causing no output to be generated, no?  This will happen if the table has upper case columns.  This will cause issues when you enable this option.

The other possibility is that your second statement isn't being run when a first statement, any statement, is being added.  You can test this by adding any other SET command (like setting enable_case_sensitive_identifier to false) and seeing if this breaks things too.

The question is how I can set enable_case_sensitive_identifier in VBA. When I add it, the sql breaks and nothing happens.

You set it just like you did.  The issue seems to be why is setting this option causing your sql to produce no output.  I've proposed 2 possibilities.
